# Is it possible to use object interfaces with Doctrine-2.1?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to create a few object interfaces like ITimestampable, INestedTree, IName, etc, and create entities that implements those interfaces to receive a common set of properties/columns.

Is it possible to do? What do you suggest?

Updated: Whould this idea work for doctrine:generate:entities and another console tools?

Comment: doctrine entities can implement whatever interfaces you like, they're just a class

Comment: And you should call your interfaces TimestampableInterface instead of ITimestampable

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The entities are just regular php classes in doctrine 2 (unlike doctrine 1), which can extend or implement whatever you like.